# Hashing as a whole

Tags: c++, hash

For one of my computer science classes, we are required to write a program that uses hashing to store a list of keys and accompanying values. The issue isn't really the hashing method, I'm just curious as to the best way to implement the data structure/what data structure to use.

Through our book and some rudimentary searching on Google, I've noticed that there isn't really a "best method" for storing the values. All I seem to encounter is the collision resolution methods of linked lists, etc.

So is there a "best" general-use data structure for hashing? This is my first time actually putting hashing into practice vs algorithmic analysis, so I haven't really got much to go off of.

Side note: I'm familiar with linked lists and to some degree trees (never used in practice).

Answer (score 1):

If this is an assignment for a computer science class, then I suggest you take the simplest scenario about hashing.

In a simple scenario your possible hash values are integers from a finite set, let's say from 0 to n-1. For that you need an array of length n.

What you store in your array is the next step... In a simple scenario you should not deal with collision algorithms. In case of a collision you just store all the elements at the same array index, in a linked list. There you have the answer on what to store in the array.

Comment: So for this solution would it be simplest to implement a class with each bucket in the hash being a linked list to allow for that form of collision resolution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. The hash is a number. The bucket may be implemented as a class containing a linked list of the elements. Then the class has n instances for the n different hash values, stored in an array or vector indexed by the hash values.

Comment: Hash table? is that more correct terminology? And that makes sense, that's what I was leaning towards in the beginning but was unsure of the logistics of it all.